# Set a rich text field in a SharePoint field to read-only via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text, read-only

I'd like to set a richtext field to read-only via Javascript/JQuery. Would be great if it works at SP 2013, 2016 and SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the field to become read only once the end user has enteded some Content?
In that case the field should be read write in the New form and read only in the Edit form which can be done by inserting a tiny script in the Edit form

An example : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/816/make-a-sharepoint-list-form-field-read-only-with-jquery.aspx

Comment: This is not working with a richt text field, since it is not an input...

Comment: Ok, does this works, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/be22077e-fffe-436c-ae5f-e4888e0a147c/how-to-disable-enhanced-rich-text-box-multiple-line-of-text-column-in-spd-form-using-jquery-in?forum=SP2016

Comment: Just remember you can edit list content in other ways. The edit form is not the only way so the content can still be changed. For example: "Quick edit"

Comment: True, but that can be disabled too. The requirement is kind of broard so NewForm could be a good starting point 

Answer (score 0):

Found it... there seems to be an additional property used by SharePoint scripts that enables and disables the field.

```
inputDivOBJ.find('[id$="inplacerte"]').prop('contenteditable','false');
```

Answer (score 0):

[SPUtility](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/WikiFiles/docs/Common%20SPField%20functions.md) plugin does this job perfectly. [Load](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/WikiFiles/docs/Installation.md#sharepoint-2010--2013--sharepoint-online-office-365) SPUtility and run the following script inside `document.ready`

```
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('InternalNameOfRichTextField').MakeReadOnly();
```

To make the field editable again use the following line

```
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('InternalNameOfRichTextField').MakeEditable();
```

This functionality works only in forms not on Quick Edit Views like most JS validation solutions